# Selenium Java compare not true?

Tags: java, selenium, logging, compare

i'm trying to compare some texts with this code bellow:

```
driver.get("https://www.hotel.de/");
boolean status = false;
String searchText = "Hannover, Niedersachsen"; 
WebElement inputBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='LocationAutoSuggest__container--2Hli_']//input"));
```

Now i send String "Hannover" to Searchbox:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(inputBox).click().sendKeys("Hannover").build().perform();
Thread.sleep(3000);
List<WebElement> listsearch = driver.findElements(By.id("react-autowhatever-1"));
```

And compare the found text with searchText :

```
for(WebElement listElem : listsearch) {
    System.out.println(listElem.getText());
    System.out.println(searchText.equals(listElem.getText()));                      

    if(searchText.equals(listElem.getText())) {                         
        System.out.println("hooho");
        status = true;
        break;
    } else {
        status = false;
    }
}

System.out.println(status);
```

==> Could you tell me: why i become FALSE instead of TRUE? (How can i see the logs, to know what was actually compared?). Many thanks.

Comment: equals method is case sensitive. You may want to use equalsignorecase method . can you post your console output?

Comment: Also, the whitespaces is what I would be looking at. I would also suggest using trim()

Comment: @ Sureshmani : equalsignorecase() i'v already used. It doesn't help.

Comment: @Kumar Rishabh: what do you mean? it doesn't make difference in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check the size of your List if it zero than directly false will be printed.
2. If size is not greater than zero check your locator.

Comment: OK, this is right way. But i don't unterstand why i'm getting size() = 1, but in the loop i become 18 items with this System.out.println(listElem.getText()); --> size() muss be 18 instead of 1 ???

Comment: As I said you are using invalid locator strategy to get all your list items. The id you are using to get list of values is of single div hence you are getting 1 as output. try to access li elements.